# Reverse Quick Sort

Tags: c++, c++11, quicksort

I am trying to perform quick sort on a given array in decreasing order but the first number output is always some arbitrary number like 456752.

I am unable to identify the source of problem. Please help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

long randPartition(long a[],long start,long end0)
{
    long pivot = start + rand()%(end0 - start);

    //swap a[end] with [pivot]
    long temp = a[end0];
    a[end0] =  a[pivot];
    a[pivot] = temp;

    //now partitioning
    long i = start;
    for(int j = start; j < end0 ; j++)
    {
        if(a[j] > a[end0])
        {
            long temp1 = a[j];
            a[j] = a[i];
            a[i] = a[temp1];
            i++;
        }
    }

    //swapping pivot with its correct position
    long temp2 = a[end0];
    a[end0] = a[i];
    a[i] = temp2;

    return i;
}

void quickSort(long ar[],long start,long end0)
{
    if (start < end0)
    {
        long i = randPartition(ar,start,end0);
        quickSort(ar,start,i-1);
        quickSort(ar,i+1,end0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int testCases;
    cin >> testCases;

    while(testCases--)
    {
        long size0;
        cin >> size0;
        long arr[size0];

        for(int i = 0; i < size0; i++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i];
        }
        //cin >> endl;

        //using quick sort algo
        quickSort(arr, 0, size0 - 1);

        //printing the sorted array
        for(int j = 0; j < size0; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably you messed the starting index somewhere (1 instead of 0). Find it out by debugging.

Comment: i have tried debugger but i always get lost! for single element it's working fine

Comment: `cin >> size0;  long arr[size0];` This is not c++, it should not compile

Comment: Debug a two-element array. That should be small enough that you don't get lost. The practical answer is to just use the built-in qsort function instead of trying to write (and debug) your own.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot VLA gcc extension

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Strictly speaking, you're right, but gcc [allows it](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

Comment: @bolov Yup­. Use vector instead.

Comment: why is size0; and long arr[size0] not allowed in c++

Comment: You have an error in randPartition().

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside randomPartition() At the line with

```
a[i] = a[temp1];
```

replace it with

```
a[i] = temp1;
```

just a booboo :P

Answer (score -1):

quickSort(arr, 0, **size0 - 1**);  and j **<** end0   exclude your last value.